# typecasting android activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to create a set of methods which can be used by different activities within my app. So I decided to put these methods into a class `Util.java` as shown below:

```
class Util{

    MainActivity activity;

    //constructor
    public Util(MainActivity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    //other methods are here
}
```

Now the above code works fine while creating an instance of `Util` from `MainActivity`. If I wanted to create an instance of `Util` form another activity, say `NewActivity` I would have to add a new constructor which accepts `NewActivity` as an argument.

**Question:**
Is there a way I can avoid multiple constructors within the Util class as below?

```
class Util{

    Activity activity; //can hold instance of any activity

    //constructor
    public Util(activity activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    //other methods are here
}
```

The above code is not useful in case I want to access the ActionBar of the current activity as shown below.

```
activity.getSupportActionBar() //would throw an error
```

In short what I'm trying to do is to create a single variable `activity` which can hold any activity(`MainActivity` or `NewActivity`) and give me full access to the members of the activity currently assigned.

Comment: Multiple constructors isn't the problem. It's multiple instances. Please show a [mcve] of how you would use this class because it seems like a poor design

Comment: It sounds like you need to write an abstract class that extends Activity, then all your other activity classes extend from that

Comment: Is it a good idea to create an abstract class for activities in android? if it was google would have done it for US.

Comment: Why would they do that? There's nothing bad about abstract activities. Why would you ever want a `new BaseActivity`? What would you put in `onCreate` if you never are going to show that Activity? It's just a holding area for all common Activity code of your app.

Comment: Obviously, `getSupportActionBar()` only works with FragmentActivity and its subclasses, so storing the regular Activity class isn't going to work

Comment: My MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity and Im able to access getSupportActionBar using the instance of the MainActivity.

Comment: Creating an abstract class looks like a pretty good idea. but then I would have to declare all the methods I want to access, wouldn't I? Please let me know if there is another way

Comment: `AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity`, so you can access that method, yes... I'm saying `abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity`, and `MainActivity extends BaseActivity`. Make Util store a BaseActivity and put whatever common code for your Activities in that BaseActivity class.

Comment: Thanks so much...your answer worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics

```
public class Util<E extends Activity> {
        E activity;
        public void doSomething(E activity) {

        }
    }
```

Access like this:

```
Util<MainActivity> util = new Util<>();
util.doSomething(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Tried this, but wasn't able to access the below method.activity.getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: I would like to access all the members of the actual Activity

Comment: @SanuSoman Create interface `IgetSupportActionBar` which has `getSupportActionBar` method, make your activities implement this interface, and constraint `E` to `IgetSupportActionBar` like this `Util<E extends IgetSupportActionBar>`

Comment: I think I'll go with cricket_007's answer, its much simpler, thanks for your help.